# Add Google Charts p Property to JSON in PHP

Tags: php, json, google-visualization

I'm trying to add the Google Charts p property to JSON data in PHP for a Table Chart but I can't get it to work.

```
$options = mysqli_query($con, $sql_sub[3]);

$rows = array();
$table = array();

$table['cols'] = array(
    array('label' => 'Information','type' => 'string'),
    array('label' => '#Number','type' => 'number'),
);

$row = mysqli_fetch_row($options);
$sub_array = array();
$sub_array[] = array("v" => 'Dropped by OPTIONS');
$sub_array[] = array("v" => $row[0]);
$sub_array[] = array("p" => "{'className': 'subrows'}");
$rows[] =  array("c" => $sub_array);

$table['rows'] = $rows;
echo json_encode($table);
```

Where "subrows" is defined as:

```
.subrows {
    background-color: darkblue;
}
```

On the client side I have the following Javascript function that requests the JSON data and draws the table:

```
function draw_table(pageID, chartID) {

    fetch(fullUrls[chartID]).then(function (response) {
        response.json().then(function (json) {
            let data = new google.visualization.DataTable(json);
            let cssClassNames = { 'headerRow': 'headerRow', 'tableCell': 'tableCell', 'oddTableRow': 'oddTableRow' };
            let table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById(`table_div_${graphs[chartID]}`));
            table.draw(data, { height: '100%', allowHtml: true, cssClassNames: cssClassNames });
        })
    })
        .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))
}
```

I expect the background color of this row to be dark blue, but it isn't.

Documentation I found here: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataview-class, just above the "DataView Class" section.

There are two related questions but I can't apply their solution on my case.

Thanks in advance.

Julian

Comment: This just creates some arrays. You haven't written any code to convert anything to JSON. You haven't written any code to output any data. You need to provide a [mcve] with a *clear problem statement* (which should include what output you get and how it differs from what you expect).

Comment: If you try the stuff first with a fixed, prepared JSON (without PHP and dynamic values) and it works, then compare it to your dynamically generated JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the [Data Format](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/table#data-format) for the Table chart

the `className` property can only be applied to the cell, not the row

you'll have to assign the `className` to every column,
in this case, use the following php...

```
$sub_array = array();
$sub_array[] = array("v" => 'Dropped by OPTIONS', "p" => array('className' => 'subrows'));
$sub_array[] = array("v" => $row[0], "p" => array('className' => 'subrows'));
$rows[] =  array("c" => $sub_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You mix already-to-JSON converted stuff with to-be-converted-to-JSON stuff.

```
$sub_array[] = array("p" => "{'className': 'subrows'}");
```

This should look like this, otherwise it would be double-encoded:

```
$sub_array[] = array("p" => array('className' => 'subrows')));
```

Furthermore, you need to make sure your visualization does make use of the p and className (from the docs):

> If your visualization supports any datatable-level properties, it will
>   describe them; otherwise, this property will be available for
>   application use.

Also, this syntax looks like a mistake or mix of PHP and Javascript:

```
let table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById(`table_div_${graphs[chartID]}`));
```

Maybe it should have `<?php echo ... ; ?>` in it.